# Is it possible to redeploy released artifacts to a release repository in Artifactory?

Tags: maven, artifactory

Is this configurable in Artifactory and is it at all allowed? In Nexus there is a configurable option for this.

Any, yes, I am very aware of why you shouldn't generally be doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Artifactory requires a user to have the "Delete" permission in order to overwrite release artifacts.

[Prevent Overwriting Deployments](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions#ManagingPermissions-PreventingOverwritingDeployments)

Comment: Thanks for this clarification! I was expecting to see it as an option under the configuration of the repository itself!